# Send to Kindle on Chrome -- multiple accounts

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, amazon-web-services, kindle

On a shared system when trying to run the `SendToKindleForPC-installer.exe` program I'm prompted for an Admin password which I don't have.

Both Chrome and Edge are installed as browsers.  Of course, I cannot install Firefox.  I installed the [extension for chrome](https://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/chrome) but that's linked to a different profile.

Operating system from `ver` on CLI: `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]`

Could I possibly run several instances of Chrome so that different instances are signed into different Kindle accounts?  I tried incognito mode but the extension doesn't seem to work from there.

Not wanting to sign into an account from the "main" chrome instance.  Looking for a work-around.

[image: kindle]

see also:

https://askubuntu.com/q/1018034/45156

Comment: You have to explicitly enable addons to run under incognito mode. Should be a tick box under the normal extensions menu.

Comment: @MichaelFrank  would you elaborate?  I've looked in regular chrome and incognito but see no such option.

Comment: Sure, here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUGoV.jpg

Comment: You do know you can “Send to Kindle” through email right?

Comment: Simplest way would be to use multiple Firefox user profiles each configured to a different account.  Seems a lot of work that a simple email to your kindle email address can solve though

Comment: @Ramhound no firefox on this Windows machine.  Just chrome :(

Comment: Solution is the same.  Use multiple user profiles and a shortcut to launch each of them.  Firefox was a typo.

Comment: per @MichaelFrank incognito works for now!  I'll look into profiles.